# SQL File Upload to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm fairly new to databases. I want to upload a .sql file to a mysql server. However the database I want to update contains many .frm .myi .myd files. Should I delete those files and replace with the .sql?

Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: from shell "mysql -u yourserver -p -D dbname < your_sql_script.sql"

Comment: What will "uploading" the .sql file accomplish?  For example does the .sql file contain commands to create tables you wish to deploy on your database server?

Answer (score 0):

Back up the old database files to a dump using `mysqldump -u username -p database_name > dump.sql` then import the new sql file using `mysql -u username -p database_name < new_sql_file.sql`.